# In unix I used kill command by providing a ppid then it close the terminal . why? kill -9 ppid

Tags: linux, terminal, kill, pid

```
sleep 5000
```

In one terminal and in second terminal I'm running:

```
ps -ef | grep sleep
```

Then I'm killing this process in second terminal by using the ppid. Then it will close the first terminal where I run the sleep command. It will not create sleep command as an orphan.

```
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
trainee   4887  4864  0 17:05 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 5000
trainee   4889  4264  0 17:05 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep
```

```
kill -9 4864
```

Why?

Comment: `ps` is displaying processes' PID and parent PID (‘PPID’), and you seem to be looking in the wrong column, thus killing *the parent* of `sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the parent of the sleep is your shell. When you kill that your login is terminated and your terminal closes.

The Wikipedia article on [Orphan process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process) reads (in part),

> An orphan process is a computer process whose parent process has finished or terminated, though it remains running itself.

and

> A process can be orphaned unintentionally, such as when the parent process terminates or crashes. The process group mechanism in most Unix-like operation systems can be used to help protect against accidental orphaning, where in coordination with the user's shell will try to terminate all the child processes with the SIGHUP process signal, rather than letting them continue to run as orphans.

Comment: yes shell is the parent of sleep. tell me if I kill the parent then all the child processes of that parent also get killed or what